# heroku, thin rack 1.1.0, gemfile requires rack 1.0.1

Tags: heroku, rubygems, rack, thin

My ror app runs on rails 2.3.5(which requires rack 1.0.1),
thin on heroku activates rack 1.1.0 by default

and throws error:

```
    " You have already activated rack 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.0.1. Consider using bundle exec."

    my Gemfile:

source 'http://rubygems.org'


group :test, :development do
  gem "rack","1.0.1"
end

gem "rails","2.3.5"
gem "mysql"
gem "rake", "0.8.3"
gem "declarative_authorization", "0.5.2"
gem "searchlogic"
gem "prawn", "0.6.3"
gem "thin","1.2.11"

group :test, :development do
  gem "rack","1.0.1"
end


group :development do
  # bundler requires these gems in development
  # gem "rails-footnotes"
end

group :test do
  # bundler requires these gems while running tests
  # gem "rspec"
  # gem "faker"
end
----------------------
```

I installed bundler and  developed Gemfile.lock    :

```
    GEM
      remote: http://rubygems.org/
      specs:
        actionmailer (2.3.5)

          actionpack (= 2.3.5)
        actionpack (2.3.5)
          activesupport (= 2.3.5)
          rack (~> 1.0.0)
        activerecord (2.3.5)
          activesupport (= 2.3.5)
        activeresource (2.3.5)
          activesupport (= 2.3.5)
        activesupport (2.3.5)
        daemons (1.1.4)
        declarative_authorization (0.5.2)
        eventmachine (0.12.10)
        mysql (2.8.1)
        prawn (0.6.3)
          prawn-core (>= 0.6.3, < 0.7)
          prawn-format (>= 0.2.3, < 0.3)
          prawn-layout (>= 0.3.2, < 0.4)
          prawn-security (>= 0.1.1, < 0.2)
        prawn-core (0.6.3)
        prawn-format (0.2.3)
          prawn-core
        prawn-layout (0.3.2)
        prawn-security (0.1.1)
        rack (1.0.1)
        rails (2.3.5)
          actionmailer (= 2.3.5)
          actionpack (= 2.3.5)
          activerecord (= 2.3.5)
          activeresource (= 2.3.5)
          activesupport (= 2.3.5)
          rake (>= 0.8.3)
        rake (0.8.3)
        searchlogic (2.4.28)
          activerecord (>= 2.0.0)
        thin (1.2.11)
          daemons (>= 1.0.9)
          eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
          rack (>= 1.0.0)

    PLATFORMS
      ruby

    DEPENDENCIES
      declarative_authorization (= 0.5.2)
      mysql
      prawn (= 0.6.3)
      rack (= 1.0.1)
      rails (= 2.3.5)
      rake (= 0.8.3)
      searchlogic
      thin (= 1.2.11)
    ---------------------------
```

Please help me deploy it on heroku........

Answer (score 0):

Solved it...

my app uses rack 1.0.1 , rails 2.3.5

and heroku activates rake 1.1.0 by default..

so i switched my rails app version to 2.3.11 which uses rack 1.1.2 in environment.rb and created a Gem file,
installed bundler

tested on my laptop...

generated lock file and pushed it to heroku...

finally worked....

took a week to get my app working...

:)